# Maximum field that can be defined in Process Builder condition

Tags: formula, process-builder

We have set of field that we need to detect changes in the object for validation rule, it around 71 (because it getting bigger) and it hit formula character limit.
So we move to Process Builder to get over the exception and use Formula evaluates to true and list down all ISCHANGE(field) and it also hit the exceed character exception.

Just curious before I try to use Conditions are met and define each field and hit the error, I really want to know how many fields that we can define per condition.

I look around [Process Limit](https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=process_limits.htm&type=5) and not able to find it.

Comment: Process Builder does not do validation, though. What exactly is your plan?

Comment: Also, you should ideally not have a single validation rule to validate 70+ fields. You can use multiple rules, it's not a crime to do so.

Comment: my plan is to detect the changes of the set of  field in process builder and update one place holder field. In validation rule, i just need to check whether any changes on place holder field to throw error. I know is not ideal, the scenario is user want to be able to update certain field and we need to lock certain field. I am thinking about trigger but I also need other alternative beside code. Do you have across anything like this before? What approach that you think might be good?

Comment: Have you looked at Record Types, Page Layouts, Field Level Security, Permission Sets? There's a ton of ways to lock down fields without a rule. Also, you can have 100+ validation rules on an object, so if you really wanted to, you could write a bunch of rules. There's no need to get complicated.

Comment: FLS , page layout cannot be applied because we want it to be lock depending on status field and other reason.Two validation rules is ideal for our case OMG we never thought of it. We are complicated. Thanks @sfdcfox

Comment: you could generalize this by creating a fieldset and using a simple apex method (trigger) to set a Boolean field 'has_changed__c`. then you can maintain the app by simply adding to and subtracting from field set members